# Matlab Bayesian Newtork toolbox and continuous values

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I have two problems, one about theory and one about implementation:

**Theory** First I have not fully understood how to work a Bayesian network with continuous values. I have learned that I can approximate P(A) (the probability of node A) with a Gaussian Distribution. But I have a dataset, mean and variance of the Gaussian Distribution is the mean and the variance of the dataset ?

And if I have P(A|B,C), with A and B with continuous values, how I can represent this with a Gaussian Distribution?

**The practical problem** is that I need to learn a Bayesian Structure from a continuous valued dataset and I use this toolbox for Matlab: http://code.google.com/p/bnt/ (Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab by Kevin Murphy)

Now how I can use to learn a Bayesian Structure from a dataset (of continuous values) with this tool?

If I use the `learn_struct_K2` function I need the order of nodes but where can I get this order? Are there other useful functions in this toolbox that you know of that can aid me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link will help you,

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13562-structure-learning-package-for-bayes-net-toolbox